# Doubt during derivation of Ehrenfest's theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I was reading about the derivation of [Ehrenfest's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) in [this](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node36.html) website when I came across this step:

> Substituting from  Schrödinger's equation (137) and simplifying, we obtain $$\frac{d\langle p\rangle}{dt}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\right)+V(x)\frac{\partial|\psi|^2}{\partial x}\right]dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}V(x)\frac{\partial|\psi|^2}{\partial x}dx$$

What I cannot understand is how the first term
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d\psi^*}{dt}  \frac{d\psi}{dx}$$ between the limits $x=\infty$ and $x=-\infty$
reduces to zero. I know $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ go to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity but why does this term reduce to zero?